# Typescript build error using Font awesome with Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, font-awesome

I followed the instructions on the font awesome website for setting them up in Vue. In my main.ts file, I am getting a typescript error even though the icons work fine.

Argument of type FunctionalComponentOptions

The error occurs on this line on FontAwesomeIcon

```
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

The error is *Argument of type 'FunctionalComponentOptions, PropsDefinition>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions, DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition>, Record>'.
  Types of property 'render' are incompatible.*

It's occurring because of this index.d.ts file. If I change it to **any** it would work.

```
declare module '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome' {
  import { FunctionalComponentOptions } from 'vue'
  export const FontAwesomeIcon: FunctionalComponentOptions
  export const FontAwesomeLayers: FunctionalComponentOptions
  export const FontAwesomeLayersText: FunctionalComponentOptions
}
```

Even if I use all the identical code from (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs) I still get the error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, using `"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.3"`